# Laravel redirect to password reset after email verification

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a Laravel project based on https://laravel-boilerplate.com/ where a superuser can create other users, therefore after account creation an email is sent to the user for verification.
The idea is to redirect to the "reset password" screen so that newly registered users can enter their password.  I believe the redirection is done in VerifiesEmails.php however :

1. the email verification requires the user to be logged in.
2. VerifiesEmails.php is kept in vendors/../Illuminate/Foundation/Auth.. and I don't want to start messing up with files in vendors folder.

What is a good way of achieving redirection to password reset after email validation ? (users not being logged in yet)

Comment: One suggestion is to ask them to login with the credentials and then change the password after that

Comment: I thought about that..like setting a temporary password, unfortunately that's not what the client demands..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed with the client, email verification is not required anymore, a simple mail with password modification request is sent instead.

Comment: less expensive to implement for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can skip the verification step, and send a password reset email directly instead.

You can customize the email template to look like it's a verification email.